# Disabled/Enabled Field From Radiobutton When in Edit Mode

Tags: php, mysql

it's me again. I don't know how or what sentence's should I mentioned about my question, so I'm very sorry.

I just want to ask: "*How to make the same choices when in edit mode?*"

What I meant is, I have this Javascript Code:

```
function setReadOnly(obj)
{
if(obj.value == "yes")
{
document.forms[0].pet_amount.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
document.forms[0].pet_amount.readOnly = 0;
} else {
document.forms[0].pet_amount.style.backgroundColor = "#eeeeee";
document.forms[0].pet_amount.readOnly = 1;
}
}
```

The function above worked fine. My html form like this (Entry the data):

```
<td>Pet Choice's</td>
<td>:</td>
<td>
<input type=radio name="pet" id="pet" value="yes" checked onclick="setReadOnly(this)">Yes
<input type=radio name="pet" id="pet" value="no" onclick="setReadOnly(this)">No
<br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Pet Amount</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="pet_amount" size="30" id="pet_amount"></td>
</tr>
```

**Explanation:** When user choose "*Yes*" then the field "*Pet Amount*" will enable, and if choose "*No*" then it will disable.

There is no problem with that, then user save it and stored to database. *But the problem is* when user want to edit the data, the default radio button is on "*Yes*" even though user was choosing "*No*" in the first place. So they have to choose it again. If they not pay attention well, the data will automatically changed when they press the update button without knowing the "*Pet*" data was changed.

Below is my edit form (html and php script):

```
<tr>
<td>Pet Choice's</td>
<td>:</td>
<td>
<input type=radio name="pet" id="pet" value="yes" checked onclick="setReadOnly(this)" <?php if($data['pet'] == 'Yes'){ echo 'checked'; } ?>>Yes
<input type=radio name="pet" id="pet" value="no" onclick="setReadOnly(this)" <?php if($data['pet'] == 'No'){ echo 'checked'; } ?>>No
<br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Pet Amount</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="pet_amount" size="30" id="pet_amount" value="<?php echo $data['pet_amount']; ?>" required></td>
</tr>
```

I've been searching in stackoverflow regarding my problem, but mostly the question is how to - radio button - enable/disable, but there are nothing about how to - radio button - enable/disable - in edit mode.

Hope you guys can help me. I've tried to changed the javascript with my own logic, but no results... :p

Comment: Remove `checked` from the line `value="yes" checked onclick="setReadOnly(this)"`

Comment: You can hard code `Pet Amount` as `0` while inserting in SQL if user has selected `NO`. This will eliminate the SQL error.

Comment: @PrerakSola: Well I did that already, the result is no radio button was checked and when I clicked the update button the sql said that it can't be null. The problem is I have to store the variable "Yes/No" value to the database eventhough the textbox is blank if I choose "No".

Comment: And in my first comment I said to remove `checked` from your edit form and not from your entry data form.